# In Themes, why does 'Reset to Default Value' result in black?

Tags: customization, theme

If you change a color in *User Preferences > Themes*, and then try to change it back to it's default by *Right click > Reset to Default Value*:

[image]

It just makes R=0, G=0 and B=0, (Black)! Why?

[image]

I know there is a 'Reset to Default Theme' button at the bottom of the Preferences window, but that resets the whole Theme.

Comment: I have noticed this happening in many other places besides themes.. (if it doesn't reset to the default value, it seems to set it to zero)

Answer (score 3):

As it says in this [bug report](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=498&aid=25274&group_id=9),  there are some default values which are hardcoded into blender, and not read from the startup .blend  (which is what the *Reset To Default Value* operator does)

This is a [known bug](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=23538&group_id=9&atid=498) on the blender wiki [todo list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/Simple_Todos#RNA).

Comment: This case is a bit different but generally it isn't recommended to post links to bug reports or todos as answers. Doing so only clarifies OP's post and often doesn't actually answer the question. If the issue _is_ indeed a bug, leave a comment on the question. See [How should we handle questions about features not yet in Blender?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now that I know its a bug, I don't need an answer. :)