# Reset OpenGL lights?

Tags: light, customization

I recently changed the lighting in the viewport in the system preferences.

[image]

How can I rest the positions of the lights? The *Reset to Default Value* does not work. it simple sets them all to a top light.

How can I reset the direction of the lamps without restoring factory defaults?

Comment: This is really inconsistent, by having it reset to this, one would think that these are the true defaults and the actual startup has modified values. Perhaps open a ticket?

Comment: @iKlsR I will post a bug report

Comment: @Vader This is a known issue, see [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1951/599).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the defaults by opening a new instance of blender and loading the defaults (without saving the default.blend) and using python to get the default values:

```
import bpy

for light in bpy.context.user_preferences.system.solid_lights:
    print(light.direction)
```

Which will print:

```
<Vector (-0.8920, 0.3000, 0.9000)>
<Vector (0.5880, 0.4600, 0.2480)>
<Vector (0.2160, -0.3920, -0.2160)>
```

So to set the light directions to the defaults, run:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.user_preferences.system.solid_lights[0].direction = (-0.892, 0.3, 0.9)
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.solid_lights[1].direction = (0.5880, 0.4600, 0.2480)
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.solid_lights[2].direction = (0.2160, -0.3920, -0.2160)
```