# How to acess and change solid OpenGL lights settings via python?

Tags: python, 3d-view, customization, opengl

I have interested in create an addon to help on viewing models.

the idea is the properties for solid OpenGL Ligths be found in tools panel so we can easily tweak the colors and light direction for better viewing.

[image: i need cahnge it via python]

But I need acess the properties in user preferences change it and save the props in the .blend and of couse automaticaly load it when a file is open.

Comment: Depends on how you'd like to change the settings of the lights... ? Related: [How to reset OpenGl for Solid lighting?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23952/3710) In order to [display the settings on a custom panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBZyg.png) only, right click the property and select *Edit Source* to see how that's done, then re-use all relevant parts in your custom panel. Related: [Copy existing property from e.g. Properties window to a custom panel](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43953/3710). Custom Lights Panel: https://gist.github.com/p2or/fc3fb7b177bf81c128e6cb03b64e85e5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you hover the color boxes with the mouse cursor you will find that the responsible python struct is `UserSolidLight` with the following properties

> base class — `bpy_struct`
>
> class `bpy.types.UserSolidLight(bpy_struct)` Light used for OpenGL
>   lighting in solid draw mode
>
> `diffuse_color` Diffuse color of the OpenGL light
>
> Type: float array of 3 items in [0, inf], default (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>
> `direction` Direction that the OpenGL light is shining
>
> Type: float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf], default (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
>
> `specular_color` Color of the light’s specular highlight
>
> Type: float array of 3 items in [0, inf], default (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>
> `use`
>   Enable this OpenGL light in solid draw mode
>
> Type: boolean, default False

According to the [Python API Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UserSolidLight.html)

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer can't currently be removed because of being the accepted answer.