# How to store Settings in txt-file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to store render settings and other settings in a txt-file.
Sadly I was not able to find a proper solution on google.

Is there an accurate way get the settings, store them in a file
and put them back in an other file?

Example, store this:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_EEVEE'

bpy.context.scene.eevee.taa_render_samples = 45

bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_motion_blur = False
```

And get it back in another file.

Comment: https://gifguide2code.com/2016/10/08/python-how-to-put-blender-data-into-a-text-file/

https://blenderartists.org/t/bpy-ops-text-open-use-and-access-data-of-the-read-text-file/512901

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34018/python-script-that-reads-text-file-containing-coordinates-and-creates-a-path-cur

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134620/15543

Comment: I've seen that before, but it's not what I'm looking for. As you can see in the Example, it's not just about storing numbers. The second question is, how can I ask blender for the whole lines of code above. If there is a way for that, I can maybe store the code-lines as strings and then work with that somehow.

Comment: There is nothing about a txt-file, storing informations and getting them back in another blend-file out of the txt-file.

Comment: Is this regarding my comment re the presets system?  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html#preset-menus which  is used to both create a text file of selected properties and read and set from it.  Pertaining to the example link would change `obj = bpy.context.object` to `scene = bpy.context.scene` and work from there.  Could you please edit code markdown into question.

Comment: Related and Possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74979/how-to-create-a-preset

Comment: Well... I'm working on my first addon - that's maybe why I'm confused. The link you shared https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134613/can-python-operator-presets-be-shared-between-operators/134620#134620   is exactly what I'm looking for. But I cant see, where the txt. file gets written to a directory. I know commands like "with open(file_to_open,'w') as file"  or similar, but there is nothing like thtat. Which commands exactly store the preset_values?     Sorry for that beginner-question...

Comment: Ping: @batFINGER

Comment: Run `bpy.utils.script_paths("presets")` in console. Shows the root of the presets path.  The I/O is done for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set settings:

```
import bpy
import json

my_txt = '''
{
    "render": {
        "engine": "BLENDER_EEVEE"
    },
    "eevee": {
        "taa_render_samples": 45,
        "use_motion_blur": false
    }
}
'''

render_settings = json.loads(my_txt)

for section in render_settings.keys():
    for name, value in render_settings[section].items():
        setattr(getattr(bpy.context.scene, section), name, value)
```

To get primitive settings:

```
import bpy
import inspect

primitive_types = {int, str, float, bool}

section = bpy.context.scene.render

def is_valid(i):
    if i[0].startswith('_'):
        return False
    if not type(i[1]) in primitive_types:
        return False
    if section.is_property_readonly(i[0]):
        return False
    return True

settings = inspect.getmembers(section, lambda i: not(inspect.isroutine(i)))
settings = dict([i for i in settings if is_valid(i)])

for name, value in settings.items():
    print(name, value)
```

Comment: That looks great. I guess I need to learn a lot about json - without that knowledge, I'm not realy able to understand the script. Thank you both for the help!