# Would it be possible to write an addon that highlights all modified settings?

Tags: scripting, interface, customization

Most if not all settings have an item *Reset to Default Value* in the context menu.
This would be helpful when tracking down issues when someone played a bit to much with the settings.

Could an addon be created to highlight changed settings, or would this require to change implementation of blender to adjust all hardcoded default values to the values of the default scene?

Can an hook-method be defined to intercept calls to draw an UI control so that the changed settings could be highlighted in one piece of code?

Apart from that there currently is a [bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/in-themes-why-does-reset-to-default-value-result-in-black/1951#1951) regarding the default settings.

Comment: That's a bug with *reset to default value*, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1951/599.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks, I changed the question now it no longer focuses on the bug.

Comment: The default value can be queried via `*.bl_rna.properties[prop_name].default`. But it is not possible to alter the drawing of ui elements.

Comment: The colour used comes from the theme, keyed, driven or default colour is chosen within the c code that draws the items. We don't really have control of the display - we only say "show a property here", blender decides how it is displayed.

Comment: @sambler Could you add your comment as an answer

Comment: Not all properties have `.default` values as you might expect, the render resolution dimensions are 4x4 for instance. The 1920x1080@50% settings come from the startup.blend - see https://developer.blender.org/T32894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a "GUI" toolkit that gives access to the objects drawing the items on screen, in blender we don't really have control of the display - we only say "show a property here", blender then decides how it is displayed.

The colour used to draw each item comes from the theme - keyed, driven or default colour is chosen within the c code that draws the items.

Comment: There's a flag you can set with Python however to show certain elements in red: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout#bpy.types.UILayout.alert

Comment: @CoDEmanX thanks, this could help to implement it at least partially.

Comment: @stacker You should word this into answer if you get it working.